# orderBy en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un controlador que envía a la vista un listado de matriculas por asignatura, cada matricula pertenece a un alumno.

```
public function showCalificacionesAsignatura($id)
{
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($id);
    $matriculados = $asignatura->matriculas;
```

En la vista recibo las matriculas y uso su relacion con el alumno para mostrar sus datos :

```
@foreach ($matriculados as $m)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$m->alumno->apellido_paterno." ".$m->alumno->apellido_materno." ".$m->alumno->nombre}}</td>
```

como puedo ordenar dichos nombres de los alumnos con orderBy('apellido_paterno','DESC')?

modelo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo Alumno

```
public function matriculas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Matricula','id_alumno');
}
```

Modelo Matricula

```
public function alumno()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class,'id_alumno','id')->orderBy('apellido_paterno','DESC');
}

public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Curso::class,'id_curso','id');
}

public function notas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Nota','id_matricula');
}

public function asignaturas() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asignatura')->orderBy('nombre','ASC');
}
```

Modelo Asignatura

```
public function matriculas() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Matricula')->withTimestamps(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si siempre vas a querer que la relación sea ordenada por apellidos bien puedes añadir el order by a dicha relación

Te dejo este ejemplo, como no has puesto el modelo, seguramente no se adapte, pero te dará la idea de como hacerlo

```
/* relación dentro del modelo */
public function matriculas() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Matricula')->orderBy('apellido_paterno', 'DESC');
}
```

Otra solución sin mucha complicaciones es hacer la consulta más directa:

```
$matriculados = Alumno::select( 'Asignatura.*', 'Matricula.*', 'Alumno.*' )
->join( 'Matriculas', 'Alumno.idalumno', '=', 'Matricula.idalumno' )
->join( 'Asignatura', 'Matricula.idasignatura', '=', 'Asignatura.idasignatura' )
->where('Asignatura.idasugnatura', '=', $id )
->orderBy('Alumno.apellido_paterno', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: Lo intente, pero no me resulto, edite la pegunta creo que no era clara.

Comment: Gracias por agregar más info, según veo esta pelícano la respuesta que te di de forma incorrecta. Fijate que llamas al modelo Asignatura : **Asignatura::find($id);** y luego al método matriculas de dicho modelo, es en esta metodo/relación en el que tendrás que realizar el ordenamiento.

Comment: Te edito la respuesta para que se adapte a tu pregunta ahora que añadís te nueva info

Comment: Gracias me sirvio :)

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que precargar la relación con Eager Loading y hacer la consulta para ordenarla en esta, algo así:

```
$asignatura = Asignatura::with(['matriculas' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('apellido', 'desc');
}])->find($id);
```

Asumo que la relación se llama `matriculas`.

---

Después de la modificación de la pregunta el panorama cambia, y creo que la solución que mejor se ajusta es utilizar el tipo de relación `hasManyThrough` para pasar de asignatura a alumnos a través de matrículas:

Modelo Asignatura:

```
public function alumnos()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Matricula', 'App\Alumno',
        'asignatura_id', 'matricula_id', 'id'
    )->orderBy('apellido_paterno', 'desc');
}
```

En el controlador lo puedes llamar así, aunque NO hay necesidad:

```
$alumnos = $asignatura->alumnos;
```

Sin embargo para evitar esa línea innecesaria, yo simplemente haría la iteración en la vista en `$asignatura->alumnos`

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero quede un poco perdido, se supone que recibo a los alumnos con $alumnos = $asignatura->matriculas; en la vista recorro a los alumnos con $alumnos->alumno(relación matricula alumno)->nombre

Comment: Entonces te faltó agregar información a la pregunta y estás nombrando mal las variables, la variable `$alumnos` en teoría debería contener alumnos, ¿no?

Comment: la variable $alumnos recibe los matriculados en esa asignatura, y en esa matricula esta el id_alumno, y quiero ordenarlos por apellido

Comment: ¿Tal vez sería mejor que llames la variable `$alumnosMatriculados` o `$matriculados`? para diferenciarla de los verdaderos "alumnos", no es lo mismo.

Comment: Pregunta editada

Comment: Editado, aunque no está probado el código.

Comment: Unknown column 'alumnos.id_asignatura' in 'field list'

Comment: Revisa los nombres de los campos de las tablas y modelos.

Comment: la tabla alumnos no tiene id_asignatura, deje el modelo en una foto. Se puede aplicar eso de la tabla intermedia en este caso? ya que tengo una relacion n a n en asignaturas y matricula por ende tengo creada la tabla pivote y en esa tabla tengo la id_asignatura y id_matricula

Comment: Por favor agrega también los modelos de Laravel, donde defines las relaciones entre las tres tablas.

Comment: listo, editado.